# Derive a new pandas column based on a certain value of a row and apply until the next value appears again

Tags: python, pandas

In a pandas dataframe string column, I want to derive a new column based on the value of a row until the next value appears again. What is the most efficient way to do this / clean way to do achieve this?

Input Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'neighborhood':['Chicago City', 'Wicker Park', 'Bucktown','Lincoln Park','West Loop','River North','Milwaukee City','Bay View','East Side','South Side','Bronzeville','North Side','New York City','Harlem','Midtown','Chinatown']})
```

My desired dataframe output would be:

```
      neighborhood city
0     Chicago City Chicago
1      Wicker Park Chicago
2         Bucktown Chicago
3     Lincoln Park Chicago
4        West Loop Chicago
5      River North Chicago
6   Milwaukee City Milwaukee
7         Bay View Milwaukee
8        East Side Milwaukee
9       South Side Milwaukee
10     Bronzeville Milwaukee
11      North Side Milwaukee
12   New York City New York
13          Harlem New York
14         Midtown New York
15       Chinatown New York
```

Comment: can you please mark the correct answer? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If the first column contains 'City', copy it to the second column but cut out the ' City' part

2) Fill NA's with a forward fill method

```
import numpy as np

df['city'] = np.where(
df.neighborhood.str.contains('City'),
df.neighborhood.str.replace(' City', '', case = False),
None)
```

Result:

```
      neighborhood       city
0     Chicago City    Chicago
1      Wicker Park       None
2         Bucktown       None
3     Lincoln Park       None
4        West Loop       None
5      River North       None
6   Milwaukee City  Milwaukee
7         Bay View       None
8        East Side       None
9       South Side       None
10     Bronzeville       None
11      North Side       None
12   New York City   New York
13          Harlem       None
14         Midtown       None
15       Chinatown       None
```

```
df['city'] = df['city'].fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

Result:

```
      neighborhood       city
0     Chicago City    Chicago
1      Wicker Park    Chicago
2         Bucktown    Chicago
3     Lincoln Park    Chicago
4        West Loop    Chicago
5      River North    Chicago
6   Milwaukee City  Milwaukee
7         Bay View  Milwaukee
8        East Side  Milwaukee
9       South Side  Milwaukee
10     Bronzeville  Milwaukee
11      North Side  Milwaukee
12   New York City   New York
13          Harlem   New York
14         Midtown   New York
15       Chinatown   New York
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.str.extract` + `ffill`

```
df['city'] = df.neighborhood.str.extract('(.*)\sCity').ffill()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just `map` a custom defined function that behaves as intended

```
city = None
def generate(s):
    global city
    if 'City' in s: city = s.replace('City','')
    return city

df['neighborhood'].map(generate)
```

this will return the intended output